# Dynamically update Animation in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I've got a property animation in QML that scrolls a list of names. It's supposed to scroll from a certain fixed y value, to the negative of its own height, so that it just exactly disappears off the screen.

However, the list of names is dynamic and can be added to at any point, therefore I want the animation to have an updated `to` value as soon as this happens. That part, I've got down, but the animation doesn't seem to be reinitialized with the new value, and retains the old animation length.

Is there any way to do what I want in QML?

Thansk.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your approach is correct.

You may want to check out the [`ListView`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-listview.html) Item and its [`positionViewAtIndex`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-listview.html#positionViewAtIndex-method) method.